# Assigning std::minmax result to new variables

Tags: c++

`auto [x, y] = std::minmax(a, b)` defines `x` and `y` as references to `a` and `b` (or `b` and `a`).

How do I make `x` and `y` new variables initialized with min and max values respectively (as if `minmax` returned pair of values instead of pair of refs)?

Comment: You could in addition to 康桓瑋's answer also use `float xy[2] = std::minmax(a, b)` or `pair<float, float> xy = std::minmax(a, b)` or `struct { float x; float y;} result = std::minmax(a, b)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the overload of the `std::initializer_list` version, which returns `pair<T, T>`.

```
auto [x, y] = std::minmax({a, b});
```